# Docker desktop pull image get HTTP status 500 Server Error

Tags: docker

I'm using `docker desktop` ,when I'm trying to pull image it bumps into following error:

> Error response from daemon: received unexpected HTTP status: 500
> Server Error

where I'm wrong?

[image]

Comment: That's a server-side error, either an issue in the Docker registry or the local daemon; with a simple `docker pull` like that, there's not going to be anything you can change in your application code to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue disappeared when I uninstalled Docker desktop and installed `docker desktop edge`.